# JS. contentEditable track changes (correction) like Word style

Tags: javascript, html, contenteditable

I'm building project Word like on contentEditable.
I know this is not the best choice to make in case of rich text editors, but still I want to track changes in the document by user, with peer-review in the end by supervisor.

I have a state, isTrackingChanges, when true - it's overrides actions, as - on insert text, insert node with underline, on backspace - get a deleted character, insert node with strikethrough style, move caret by one character to the left. At this point I have a lot of inline nodes. But on peer review I would like to accept/decline whole part of characters. How can I group them programmatically?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the problem with another solution. On accept/decline change I'm checking for Node.nextSibling() and Node.previousSibling() to get whole group. Works fine for me